# Going from Qt4 to Qt5 on Linux: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"

Tags: qt5, xcb

I'm moving from Qt4 (4.8.6) to Qt5 (5.4.1) in cross-build environment (GAR environment, MiniMyth2 project).

I have perfectly building and running Qt4.
I already successful cross-compiled and install Qt5.
For reference - here is configure output:

```
   Configure summary

Building on:   linux-g++-64-garbuild (x86_64, CPU features: mmx sse sse2)
Building for:  linux-g++-64-garhost (x86_64, CPU features: mmx sse sse2)

qmake vars .......... styles += mac fusion windows DEFINES += QT_NO_MTDEV CONFIG += use_libmysqlclient_r QT_LIBS_DBUS = -ldbus-1  QT
_CFLAGS_DBUS = -I/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/dbus-1.0
/include  QT_HOST_CFLAGS_DBUS = -I/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/bui
ld/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/include  QT_CFLAGS_GLIB = -pthread -I/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/piotro/m
inimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include  QT_LIBS_GLIB = -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lrt -lglib-2.0  QMAKE_CFLAGS_FONTCONFIG = -
I/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/include/freetype2  QMAKE_LIBS_FONTCONFIG = -lfontconfig -lfreetype  QMAKE_INCDIR_LIBUDEV
=  QMAKE_LIBS_LIBUDEV = -ludev -lrt  QMAKE_X11_PREFIX = /usr QMAKE_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT = /usr/share/X11/xkb QMAKE_CFLAGS_XCB =  QMAKE_LI
BS_XCB = -lxcb-sync -lxcb-xfixes -lxcb-randr -lxcb-render -lxcb-image -lxcb-shm -lxcb-keysyms -lxcb-icccm -lxcb-shape -lxcb  sql-dri
vers =  sql-plugins =  mysql qmake switches .........

Build options:
  Configuration .......... alsa audio-backend avx avx2 c++11 clock-gettime clock-monotonic concurrent cross_compile dbus dbus-linked
 evdev eventfd fontconfig full-config getaddrinfo getifaddrs glib iconv icu inotify ipv6ifname large-config largefile libudev linuxf
b medium-config minimal-config mremap no-harfbuzz opengl openssl-linked pcre png posix_fallocate qpa qpa reduce_exports reduce_reloc
ations release shared silent small-config sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 system-freetype system-jpeg system-png system-zlib xcb xcb-g
lx xcb-plugin xcb-xlib xinput2 xkbcommon-qt xlib xrender
  Build parts ............ libs
  Mode ................... release
  Using C++11 ............ yes
  Using gold linker....... no
  Using PCH .............. no
  Target compiler supports:
    SSE2/SSE3/SSSE3 ...... yes/yes/yes
    SSE4.1/SSE4.2 ........ yes/yes
    AVX/AVX2 ............. yes/yes

Qt modules and options:
  Qt D-Bus ............... yes (linked to dbus-1)
  Qt Concurrent .......... yes
  Qt GUI ................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............. yes
  Large File ............. yes
  QML debugging .......... no
  Use system proxies ..... no

Support enabled for:
  Accessibility .......... no
  ALSA ................... yes
  CUPS ................... no
  Evdev .................. yes
  FontConfig ............. yes
  FreeType ............... yes (system library)
  Glib ................... yes
    GTK theme .............. no
  HarfBuzz ............... no
  Iconv .................. yes
  ICU .................... yes
  Image formats:
    GIF .................. yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
    JPEG ................. yes (plugin, using system library)
    PNG .................. yes (in QtGui, using system library)
  journald ............... no
  mtdev .................. no
  Networking:
    getaddrinfo .......... yes
    getifaddrs ........... yes
    IPv6 ifname .......... yes
    OpenSSL .............. yes (linked to the libraries)
  NIS .................... no
  OpenGL / OpenVG:
    EGL .................. no
    OpenGL ............... desktop
    OpenVG ............... no
  PCRE ................... yes (bundled copy)
  pkg-config ............. yes
  PulseAudio ............. no
  QPA backends:
    DirectFB ............. no
    EGLFS ................ no
    KMS .................. no
    LinuxFB .............. yes
    XCB .................. yes (system library)
      EGL on X ........... no
      GLX ................ yes
      MIT-SHM ............ yes
      Xcb-Xlib ........... yes
      Xcursor ............ no
      Xfixes ............. yes
      Xi ................. no
      Xi2 ................ yes
      Xinerama ........... yes
      Xrandr ............. yes
      Xrender ............ yes
      XKB ................ yes
      XShape ............. yes
      XSync .............. no
      XVideo ............. yes
  Session management ..... no
  SQL drivers:
    DB2 .................. no
    InterBase ............ no
    MySQL ................ yes (plugin)
    OCI .................. no
    ODBC ................. no
    PostgreSQL ........... no
    SQLite 2 ............. no
    SQLite ............... no
    TDS .................. no
  udev ................... yes
  xkbcommon .............. yes (bundled copy, XKB config root: /usr/share/X11/xkb)
  zlib ................... yes (system library)
```

Unfortunately any attempt to rum Qt application returns:

```
root@FE-AMDe2100:~ # /usr/bin/mythfrontend.sh
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted
```

running LDD shows all libs are present I think

```
root@FE-AMDe2100:~ # /usr/local/bin/ldd -r -d /usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
/usr/local/bin/ldd: line 124: 1: not found
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1fdb8000)
        libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f7120378000)
        libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f7120166000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f711ff61000)
        libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f711fd4b000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f711fb2c000)
        libxcb-image.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-image.so.0 (0x00007f711f927000)
        libxcb-icccm.so.4 => /usr/lib/libxcb-icccm.so.4 (0x00007f711f723000)
        libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f711f51e000)
        libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007f711f317000)
        libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f711f115000)
        libxcb-randr.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0x00007f711ef08000)
        libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007f711ed04000)
        libxcb-keysyms.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb-keysyms.so.1 (0x00007f711eb02000)
        libxcb-xkb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb-xkb.so.1 (0x00007f711e8e8000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f711e6a2000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f711e3e9000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f711e100000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f711def5000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f711dbc3000)
        libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f711d4ea000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f711cdcb000)
        libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f711cb43000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f711c927000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f711c5f9000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f711c27b000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f711c066000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f711be51000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f712084a000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f711bc4e000)
        libxcb-util.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb-util.so.1 (0x00007f711ba49000)
        libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f711b67a000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f711b463000)
        libbz2.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f711b250000)
        libpcre.so.1 => /usr/lib/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f711afed000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f711ade5000)
        libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f711aba8000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f711a924000)
        libicui18n.so.54 => /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.54 (0x00007f711a4bb000)
        libicuuc.so.54 => /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.54 (0x00007f711a11b000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f7119eef000)
        libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f7119ca7000)
        libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f7119aa4000)
        libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f711989f000)
        libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f711969b000)
        libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f7119498000)
        libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f7119296000)
        libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f711908d000)
         libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f7118e8b000)
        libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f7118c86000)
        libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f7118a79000)
        libicudata.so.54 => /usr/lib/libicudata.so.54 (0x00007f711704e000)
root@FE-AMDe2100:~ #
```

I was trying to add

```
QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/

minimyth@FE-AMDe2100:~ $ env
USER=minimyth
XINITRC=/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
HOME=/home/minimyth
KDE_HOME_READONLY=1
XSERVERRC=/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc
LOGNAME=minimyth
USE_VDPAU_COLORKEY=1
TERM=linux
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/libexec:/usr/lib/qt5/bin
ICEAUTHORITY=/home/minimyth/.ICEauthority
DISPLAY=:0.0
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PERL_BADLANG=0
SHELL=/bin/ash
PWD=/home/minimyth
QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/
```

Still no go :-(

Basically I'm out of ideas where issue might be...

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but... shouldn't it be: QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/qt5/plugins ?

Comment: OMG: You are right!!!  I fell so stupid now. You know: during 4 days I manage to cross-compile 9 new Qt5 requirements (ruby, ice, all xcv stuff). I created new dedicated platform definition for host & targets.So finally I got fully clean 5.4.1 cross-compile and....spent another 3 days just to....be teached about this typo!. Thx so much for Your sharp eye and also for willingness to help!!!!!

Comment: Don't worry, I know how you feel, I did the same so much times! :-) glad to have been useful!