# Qt application trying to load platform plugin "xcb" instead of "eglfs"

Tags: arm, qml, qtwebkit, yocto, qt5.4

Built **Raspberry Pi 2** linux distro including Qt5.4 + QtWebKit + QML plugin using Yocto on `fido` branch [See tutorial](http://www.embarcados.com.br/raspberry-pi-2-qt5-yocto-parte-1/)

#### Testing with the following QML script

```
root@raspberrypi2:~# more webkit3.qml 
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtWebKit 3.0

ScrollView {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    WebView {
        id: webview
        url: "http://qt-project.org"
        anchors.fill: parent
        onNavigationRequested: {
            // detect URL scheme prefix, most likely an external link
            var schemaRE = /^\w+:/;
            if (schemaRE.test(request.url)) {
                request.action = WebView.AcceptRequest;
            } else {
                request.action = WebView.IgnoreRequest;
                // delegate request.url here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### The ERROR message

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"

Looks like it's still try to start with [XCB plugin](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html#xcb) which relates to X11 whereas I specified [EGLFS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html#eglfs) (??)

```
root@raspberrypi2:~# /usr/bin/qt5/qmlscene  webkit3.qml -platform eglfs
Unable to query physical screen size, defaulting to 100 dpi.
To override, set QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH and QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT (in millimeters).
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Any ideas why I am getting this issue?

### QT5 plugins platforms installed

```
root@raspberrypi2:/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms# ls -al
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jun 12 12:59 .
drwxr-xr-x   18 root     root          4096 Jun 12 13:03 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        601864 Jun 11 15:19 libqeglfs.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        499564 Jun 11 15:19 libqlinuxfb.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         20576 Jun 11 15:19 libqminimal.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        478500 Jun 11 15:19 libqminimalegl.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        465740 Jun 11 15:19 libqoffscreen.so
```

Please do not refer me to the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899812/going-from-qt4-to-qt5-on-linux-this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-coul) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405689/qt-5-4-1-this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-th) issues. The message is the same but not I don't think it is the same cause.

Comment: Maybe `qmlscene` is eating the arguments -- have you tried passing the `-pletform` option BEFORE the name of the qml file? Or setting the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` environment variable to `eglfs` instead of the comman line parameter?

Comment: Your suggestion worked out well!! Please add you comment as an answer for me to validate. Cheers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `qmlscene` is eating the arguments -- pass the `-platform` option BEFORE the name of the qml file, or set the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` environment variable to `eglfs` instead of the command line parameter.

For the future, you might want to make `eglfs` the default choice by configuring Qt with `-qpa eglfs`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, i had to call

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM="xxxxx"
```

before build & run.